# Duplicate Logic for Healthcare Claims Data

Tags: sql-server

I work in the healthcare field and I tend to deal with claims data often. The data is most often displayed at line level detail.

```
CLAIM CLAIMLINE
12345 1
12345 2
12345 3
12345 1
12345 2
12345 3
```

Referencing the above duplicate example, what is the best logic I can write to help identify when a claim is listed more than once? Because there is line level detail, you cannot simply do a HAVING COUNT > 'x' because the lines always cause the claim number to repeat causing inherent duplicates. I really need a way to group the claims and do a count based on the group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Unclear.   Based on your sample data, what would be your desired output?

Comment: so there are other columns you want to see when there are duplicates in column 1 and 2? is that the question here?

Comment: The desired output would be to flag this claim as a duplicate based on the grouping of claim 12345. For example, rows 1-3 above would be count 1, row 3-6 would be count 2. Ergo, Claim 12345 is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find a count of the unique combinations of `CLAIM` and `CLAIMLINE`, add a `group by` statement including the columns you want to group on and then an aggregate such as `count` either on a non-nullable column or just a given value such as the `1` below:

```
select CLAIM
      ,CLAIMLINE
      ,count(1) as RecordCount
from YourTable
group by CLAIM
        ,CLAIMLINE
order by RecordCount desc
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you iamdave!

Answer (score 0):

To return just the `claim` number for claims that have duplicate `claimline`:

```
select distinct claim
from claims c
group by claim, claimline
having count(*) > 1
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FCIW49171

returns:

```
+-------+
| claim |
+-------+
| 12345 |
+-------+
```

from example data:

```
create table claims (claim int, claimline int)
insert into claims values 
 (12345,1),(12345,2),(12345,3),(12345,1),(12345,2),(12345,3)
,(6789,1),(6789,2)
```

---

To return all rows/columns for claims that have duplicate lines:

```
select *
from claims c
  inner join (
    select distinct claim
    from claims c
    group by claim, claimline
    having count(*) > 1
    ) dup
    on c.claim = dup.claim
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use cte and row_number to get this as below:

```
;With DupeClaims as (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by claim, claimline order by claim) from yourClaims  )
 Select * from DupeClaims where RowN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also work with medical data, we run into this a lot. We will either pick the first or last record coming in, assuming you record the date the record was created. I prefer to do this using a CTE with the ROW_NUMBER function. The query below would get the latest duplicate record, to get the first remove the DESC option on the ORDER BY clause:
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text and not images.  Do you expect people that want to use this code to type it all out manually rather than copy and paste?